# Which child-view was clicked?

Tags: android, events, event-bubbling

I have a `View` which contains 4 views. I registered to the event `View.OnClickListener` by using the method `setOnClickListener`.

Is it possible to know which of the four child was pressed?

Comment: Try to compare view id with onClick view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Button1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Button2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Button3"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Button4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;
    private Button button4;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
                Toast.makeText(this,"Button 1 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                Toast.makeText(this,"Button 2 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                Toast.makeText(this,"Button 3 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                Toast.makeText(this,"Button 4 click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's actually not a bad solution. So, your assumption is that events are bubbling from down-up?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
parent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)v;

        for(int index = 0; index < parent.getChildCount(); index++){
            View child = parent.getChildAt(index);

        }
    }

});
```

Comment: What is `childImageViewA`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set tag to your views and set them to be clickable.

Later on you can get the id by `view.gettag()` inside this method

```
public void onClick(View v){
int id = v.getTag();
    switch(id){
      case 0:
      break;
      default:
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: But the event `onClick` is related to the parent. Not the children.

Comment: @AngryOliver You'll get the child which is clicked. That is why i mentioned setting tag to your view.

Answer (score 0):

for every child

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```