# Click on a specific item of a CardView in GridLayout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity, cardview

I have a simple GridLayout with 5 CardViews. I already managed it to open a different activity depending on the CardView that was clicked. Here the code:

```
//Set an event for each CardView of the GridLayout
    private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid){
        //For each Child of the GridLayout that is a CardView
        for(int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++){
            if(mainGrid.getChildAt(i) instanceof CardView) {
                CardView cardview = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
                final int index = i;
                cardview.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    if(index == 0){ //if the Card Category was clicked create event FilterCategory
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Filter.this, FilterCategory.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent,0);
                        //AND GOES ON...
     }
```

The thing is that I added a cross on the CardView with the aim that, when the user clicks that cross, the filter disappears. Here you can see how the layout looks:

[image]

How can I detect when the cross has been clicked? The cross is part of the CardView, at the moment you click it, the next activity is opened.

Thanks

Comment: could you give me the complete code. because otherwise it seems like a simple matter of assigning an id to the cross button and then setting an onClickListener on it

Comment: What is your use-case though, first dismiss the cardview when cross is clicked and then launch the activity or on click of cross it should not launch the activity and just dismiss the cardview?

Comment: @Ritesh when the cross is clicked it should dismiss the cardview and not launch the activity.

Comment: @LauraGalera In that case you need to have different listeners for cross - where you will just dismiss and other listeners for launching the new activity. As of now I assume the cardview listener consists of the whole view, including cross.

Comment: @Narendra_Nath there are 5 crosses in total, I just showed one. I guess from what you say you want to set a ClickListener for every one of them on the method onCreate(). but when you click the cross, will the activity launch? I was wondering if I could edit setSingleEvent() to detect if the cross is what was clicked.

Comment: @Ritesh the idea then is to get the id and set a ClickListener for each cross. I should do that on the method onCreate(), isn't it? But I was wondering if when the cross is clicked, the code for launching the activity will be executed as well.

Comment: @LauraGalera Yes, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712400/which-child-view-was-clicked

For cross you can just dismiss it and for others you can launch new activity.

Comment: @Ritesh the thing is that the cross is inside the CardView so when the CardView is clicked the other activity will be launched. I don't get what you mean by others because as I showed in the code the activity is launched when the CardView is clicked.

Comment: Now i got your problem. You want the cross to be clicked independent of the cardViewClick right?

Comment: Yes, at the moment I did a ClickListener for each cross, all this on the method onCreate() but it does look dirty.

Answer (score -1):

use recicler view and implements View.OnClickListener

```
public class YourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private TextView categoryText;
    private TextView categorinameText;
    private ImageView cellImagen;
    private int pocision;

    public ConsultaSalvadaViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            if(index == 0){ //if the Card Category was clicked create event   FilterCategory
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Filter.this, FilterCategory.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
                    //AND GOES ON...
 }

    }
}
```

this is the holder

Comment: I am not looking for a RecyclerView because my filters are limited, I only have 5. It would make sense to use one for Products or Categories, but not for Filters.